# Connecting to second database not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, phpbb, phpbb3

Im trying to intergrate phpbb3 with code igniter. im pretty successful but im tryying to access the forum database and it not working. This is currently what I have in my database file.

```
/** FORUM DATABASE **/

$active_group = 'forum';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['forum']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['forum']['username'] = 'root';
$db['forum']['password'] = 'root';
$db['forum']['database'] = 'phpbb';
$db['forum']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['forum']['dbprefix'] = 'phpbb';
$db['forum']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['forum']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['forum']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['forum']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['forum']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['forum']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['forum']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['forum']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['forum']['stricton'] = TRUE;

/** CMS DATABASE **/
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = 'cms';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = TRUE;
```

And here is a method that is trying to access the database. It keeps returning null.

```
public function getUserGroupMembership()
{
  $forum = $this->load->database('forum',TRUE);
  global $table_prefix;
  $userId = $this->_user->data['user_id'];
  $this->forum->select('g.group_name');
  $this->forum->from($table_prefix . 'groups g');
  $this->forum->from($table_prefix . 'user_group u');
  $this->forum->where('u.user_id', $userId);
  $this->forum->where('u.group_id', 'g.group_id', FALSE);
  $query = $this->forum->get();
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $group)
  {
      $groups[] = $group['group_name'];
  }
  return $groups;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `$forum` by `$this->forum` on the first line of the method?  `$forum` and `$this->forum` is not the same thing.

Comment: IF this was this was an answer i would be able to give it the check mark.

Comment: I've added my answer with a bit more meat to it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database object is loaded in the `$forum` variable, but the `$this->forum` variable is used to interact with the database.  It's not going to work as `$forum` is a local variable and `$this->forum` is an class variable, they aren't the same.  To fix your code, you should change `$forum` to `$this->forum` or `$this->forum` to `$forum`.  You can not use both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do not need to redeclare $active_group and $active_record for both databases.

If you remove:

$active_group = 'forum';
$active_record = TRUE;

It might work. You should also do what Maxime said and change $forum with $this->forum.

Hope this helps!